# Why does the method hash(int h) of HashMap like this?

Tags: java, hashmap

```
static int hash(int h) {
    // This function ensures that hashCodes that differ only by
    // constant multiples at each bit position have a bounded
    // number of collisions (approximately 8 at default load factor).
    h ^= (h >>> 20) ^ (h >>> 12);
    return h ^ (h >>> 7) ^ (h >>> 4);
}
```

Could someone tell me that why this hash method designned like this?What is the benefit?

Comment: Where is this code from? What is the input value?

Comment: It is java's HashMap's method. the input value is the Object's hashcode

Comment: So it's hashing a hash? I don't think that makes sense...

Comment: @Brad Unless you don't trust the hash you are given.  Have a look at the Integer.hashCode() and consider for a small map it just takes the lower 4 bits.

Comment: BTW You can extend this to other bot sizes.  The first line divides the bits into 3 slightly unequal sections and the second divide this range into 3.  This means one bit can toggle 9 bits of the result.

Answer (score 3):

If you see the [Open JDK  Source](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/HashMap.java.html),

This method have the comments...

```
/**
          * Applies a supplemental hash function to a given hashCode, which
          * defends against poor quality hash functions.  This is critical
          * because HashMap uses power-of-two length hash tables, that
          * otherwise encounter collisions for hashCodes that do not differ
          * in lower bits. Note: Null keys always map to hash 0, thus index 0.
 */
```

Comment: +1 This is done because some hashCode functions are very simple.  For example Integer.hashCode or Inet4Addess.hashCode()  As the HashMap is a power of 2 in size, it takes just the lower bits.  This means that all keys with the same lower bits would be a collision, Something very easy to do for IP addresses.